# Regresar String en una peticion de volley

Tags: android, kotlin, volley

Quiero que mi función regrese el String de la petición, pero en el return me marca `Unresolved reference: resp` si pongo la variable fuera no me marca este error pero regresa la variable en blanco, el servidor si me da respuesta ya que al poner 
`println(response.getString("Version"))` imprime 0.8

```
fun getVersion(url:String):String{

    val que = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
    val req = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,
            Response.Listener {
                response ->
                  var resp = response.getString("Version")
            }, Response.ErrorListener { error ->
        println("Error")
    }
    )
    que.add(req)

    return resp
}
```

Comment: Prueba en imprimir el response a ver cómo te devuelve los datos formateados desde el servicio web. Y copia el resultado para poder ayudarte más.

Comment: @Sebastian si imprimo el response me devuelve un JSON `{"Version":"0.8"}`, lo que no consigo es retornar la variable resp

Comment: El problema es que el request se ejecuta de manera asincronica, mientras que el return trabaja de forma sincronica. Tu metodo getVersion() esta lanzando un request e instantaneamente responde resp que se encuentra vacia. Poco despues llega desde internet la respuesta del request y se carga apropiadamente la variable resp, pero ya es muy tarde.
Investiga sobre el correcto uso de los metodos asincronicos y el uso de callbacks.

Comment: Es como dice erick, usa interfaces para crear un callback que te retorne el resultado una vez que lo obtuvo.

Comment: @ErickSilva podrías brindarme un ejemplo o algún enlace, encontré este [video](https://youtu.be/WJXQg0rQKek) pero utiliza corrutinas con [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines?hl=es-419) , también encontré esta [guia](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/coroutines-guide-ui.md) pero utiliza javaFx, y no se si es necesario implementar javaFx o crear un ViewModel para lo que quiero hacer que es retornar un String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es conceptual, cuando se trata de asincronismo no es bueno que uses un metodo esperando que retorne algo usando `return`. En su lugar debes esperar que la tarea asincronica retorne su valor llamando a otro metodo.

En internet vas a encontrar muchos tutoriales con arquitecturas mas o menos complejas explicando como lidiar con asincronismo o incluso como enmascarar el asincronismo para que simulen ser tareas sincronicas. Yo aca te muestro una forma muy basica de como trabajar en estas situaciones. Muy probablemente esto no resuelva tu problema, porque tendras que cambiar mucho mas codigo, pero es parte de dejar de pensar en una ejecucion lineal del codigo y empezar a pensarlo como realmente es, muchos hilos de ejecucion corriendo al mismo tiempo y objetos interactuando con otros.

En lugar de tener un metoro que retorna la version, ahora tu metodo solo envia la peticion, el resto de la app tendra que estar preparada para poder trabajar sin saber este dato hasta que este sea devuelto o de error.

```
fun getVersion(url:String){
  val que = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
  val req = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,
    Response.Listener { response ->
        var version = response.getString("Version")
        versionRecived(version)
      }, Response.ErrorListener { error ->
        println("Error")
  })
  que.add(req)
}
```

Deberas tener un metodo donde recibas la respuesta finalmente. Al ser una respuesta asincronica, no se puede asegurar cuando llegue la respuesta, podria tardar varios segundo o nada si es que usas algun sistema de cache. Por lo que tu app tiene que estar preparada para poder recibir esta respuesta en cualquier momento.

```
fun versionRecived(version:String){
  //Aca hace lo que tengas que hacer con el valor de la version.
}
```

Si logras pensar en cada metodo como un evento independiente de lo que paso antes o lo que pasara despues a la larga tendras codigo mas robusto y mas facil de mantener tambien.